# how does laravel finds the connection between models and its table in database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

in my model i have

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Page extends Model
{
    //
}
```

in my controller i can say `Page:all()` and get all the rows from `pages` table 
but i dont see any connection between `Page` model and `pages` table in the database

does it just guess table name based on the model name (lower case with extra s at the end ) or it's mentioned somewhere else ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As you can see in the docs, this is the magic of Laravel :-)

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#defining-models (see Table Names)

If you want, you can set another name manually by user the following

`protected $table = 'my_table_name';`

And to go a bit further, this is how Laravel gets the table name in the base Model you can found at `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php`

```
/**
 * Get the table associated with the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTable()
{
    if (isset($this->table)) {
        return $this->table;
    }

    return str_replace('\\', '', Str::snake(Str::plural(class_basename($this))));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the table by putting the below code into your model
**protected $table = 'your table name';**
Otherwise, **it takes a table name as a plural form of the model.**
For example, if your model name **Product** then by default it connects the table named **'products'.**

So **if your table name is not different then no need to configure it.** It's will connect automatically

Answer (score 0):

By default, it takes the "[snake case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case)" of the class name used in the model. Also, add a final "s" to make the plural.

You can also define a custom name by adding the variable

```
protected $table = 'my_table_name';
```

in the model class.

For instance:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 
class Flight extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'my_flights';
}
```